# Ping problems with Windows Server 2012 since Updates on 20/4/2016

Tags: updates, ping, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm getting a very strange issue with Ping on Windows Server 2012 R2.

I'm running 3 servers - call them A, B and C - and I've also been using a Windows 7 desktop to test this - call it Z.

I can Ping from any of A, B, C or Z to any of the others (i.e. all 4 machines are functioning for both inbound and outbound Pings) - EXCEPT I can't Ping from Server A to Server B (B to A works fine as do C and Z to B).

I've run WireShark on both Server A and Server B and both A and B see BOTH the Ping Request packets going from A to B - AND Ping Reply packets going back from B to A.  The Request packets have ICMP ID field as 0x0001 BUT the Reply packets have the ICMP ID field changed to 0x0100 (both the outbound packet as it leaves B and the inbound packet when it reaches A) - so the replies do not match the request and hence the Ping fails.

FWIW, given the particular values, the ID change could be a big-endian vs. little-endian byte swap, though why that might happen (and only happen in one case) makes no sense to me.

Until the Windows Updates this week (which have been applied to all of A, B, C and Z) Pings worked fine with no exceptions that I'm aware of - but the timing might, of course, be complete coincidence.

I've rebooted both A and B but that's made no difference to the behaviour.

Apart from this odd Ping issue, all of A, B, C and Z appear to be functioning normally - no connection problems / errors.

Has anyone got any idea what's going on / what's happened?  Has anyone else seen this?

I've also see the question at ==> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36764903/fail-to-send-ping-from-server, which might or might not be related.

Many thanks for any ideas / suggestions!